# Is the FROM image layer included in my image

Tags: docker, dockerhub, docker-image, docker-build

I have a Dockerfile:

```
FROM baseimage

RUN <do stuff>
```

I have a `baseimage` locally, but it's not available on Docker Hub. I build `myimage` using Dockerfile above and push `myimage` to Docker Hub.

My question is: does `myimage` include `baseimage`?

Also let's say other user pulls `myimage`. He does not have `baseimage` locally. Would he be able to pull `myimage` successfully and run?

The actual issue I experience is pull `myimage` fails for other user:

```
get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/<BASEIMAGE>: unauthorized: incorrect username or password
```

This is in spite of explicitly running beforehand

```
docker login -u <USER> https://registry-1.docker.io/
Password: 
Login Succeeded
docker login https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/<ORG>/<BASEIMAGE>/manifests/<BASEIMAGE>
Authenticating with existing credentials...
Login Succeeded
```

I thought for private images all layers, including `baseimage` would be available at `myimage`.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The force of it is to share base images between differents builds. Sorry I don't know the details about private repo.

Answer (score 0):

An image is just a stack of layers. When you have a `FROM` in a dockerfile, the build process will start the new image by adding layer on top of the layers from the `FROM` image.

Once you push an image, it push all the layers for this image included layers from the base image.

When you pull an image it will download all layers not present locally and a manifest explaining how to stack them.

Comment: I thought so too. but apparently `myimage` does not offer `baseimage` layer. Or at least the user is unable to pull it. Is there a way for me to investigate this further? I checked image layer sizes and based on sizes from docker hub and docker history the `baseimage` is really not included (baseimage is 1Gb, docker history shows `myimage` layers are 680 Mb + 1Gb `baseimage` layer, Dockerhub shows `myimage` as 680 Mb).

Comment: When you run `docker pull ` / `docker push` you have the list of layer, you can check if the list differ.